# Como usar uma imagem em aplicação android que está salva em um servidor web?

Tags: java, android, image

Tenho uma aplicação android que seleciona uma imagem do SDCard e envia pra um webservice feito em php que salva a imagem em um servidor e grava no banco de dados (MySQL) o caminho da imagem.
O que eu queria fazer agora é pegar essa imagem que está salva no servidor e exibi-la nessa mesma aplicação android. Ou seja, fazer o processo inverso de envio da imagem para a aplicação. Não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso, alguém poderia me ajudar com este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta usar bibliotecas como o Glide ou Picasso. Ex (Glide):

Adicione essas dependências no seu arquivo `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
}
```

E no código faça essa chamada:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  GlideApp.with(this).load("URL_DA_IMAGEM").into(imageView);
}
```

Mais detalhes em: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Funcionou quando eu troquei o `GlideApp` por apenas `Glide` (apesar de na documentação do Glide ter um exemplo utilizando `GlideApp`), ficando:  `Glide.with(this).load("URL_DA_IMAGEM").into(imageView);`
Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Eu também nunca usei esse GlideApp, mas como vi que saiu a versão 4, imagino que tenha sido uma mudança.